# How do I move Terraria progress from one mobile device to another?

Tags: ios, terraria-mobile

How can I move my Terraria progress from my iPhone 5s to my iPad pro without restoring? I have already tried to backup my phone and restore it with my iPad and it didn't work. Does anyone know how to move my progress. It's ok if you have a solution that requires a laptop.

Comment: Can you save your data to the cloud on the iPhone, then download it again on the iPad? I know it's possible if you own it for PC on Steam, but I'm sure if the mobile version is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Currently using the Cloud you can backup both your world and your character.

- You select the settings icon beside the world in the world menu.
- Then in the menu that appears, you click backup.

Repeat this for your character too, and you keep everything!

Then if you want to download them again, just do the same with the Cloud world.

Answer (score 1):

(This will make you have to rebuild your house, beat WoF again, all pre hardmode bosses, and whatever bosses you already beat) Get a new world on cloud save, dump your inventory and items in a chest, go on to your I-Pad, make a new world on there, get all the items, transfer it to that world, and beat all the bosses again.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to join a multiplayer game, have your old character dump his inventory somewhere, and have the new character pick up those things